# Handling form input in play framework

Tags: java, jsp, playframework, request, playframework-2.0

This is beginning to frustrate me. After reading the documentation, it looks like the typical way to handle form input in play is like this:

```
val form = Form(tuple(
           "param1" -> text,
           "param2" -> text
           )
        );
```

However, there are a few problems with this. Even when I import `play.api.data.*`, I get the following errors:

1. val cannot be resolved to a type.
2. text cannot be resolved to a variable.
3. Syntax error on "-", "--" expected.

There is zero documentation of this that I could find online.

Anybody know why this is going on? Could I be missing an import or something? These are my imports:

```
import play.*;
import play.api.data.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.*;
```

Comment: Oh, *thaaaat's* my problem. Crap. So how can I do this in java?

Comment: What are you using? Java or Scala? Because your first code piece looks like Scala, yet you tagged the question with `java` and have Java imports in the second code piece.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaForms

Comment: @Carsten nice link. How would I do it for individual form values?